# ENOENT: no such file or directory when installing react-navigation in react-native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm getting a few errors while I'm  installing react-navigation in my react native project with

`npm install @react-navigation/native`
[image]
The installation goes halfway and stops for a couple minutes and puts this error out. Can someone please help me solve this problem

The `navigation.navigate('')` is not working whenever I am trying to navigate a button to another screen.
I feel like there is some problem with the navigation thing in general as almost the same thing happens when I try installing the dependencies of the navigation into the project with

`npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

I am just starting out so I don't have much idea what I'm doing wrong.
I keep digging and post here if I find the solution.

```
java version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode)
Gradle 6.3
```

[image]

Comment: try removing node_modules and installing them again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was installing stuff while the server was running. Just stopping the server and installing again fixes it.